# Excerpt text P tag open issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Text length limited, shows the whole contents after clicking. But if someone could check the code, the first P tag opens fine, but from the 2nd one, it doesn't open completely.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function excerpt(text, len) {
    return text.substring(0, len)+"&hellip;";
}

var $div = $('.container');
$div.each(function() {
  var $p=$(this).find("p:first");
   var theExcerpt = excerpt($p.text(), 230);
    $p.data('html', $p.html()).html( theExcerpt);
});

$('span').click(function() {
    var isHidden = $(this).text() == 'Show';
   var $p = $(this).parent().find("p:first");
    var theExcerpt = excerpt($p.text(), 230);
    $p.html( isHidden ? $p.data('html') : theExcerpt);
    $(this).remove();
});

});​
```

Online sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M6wzh/).

If I have `return text.substring(0, len)+"&hellip;" + <span>show</span>;`
http://jsfiddle.net/M6wzh/3/

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this just by altering the HTML: the `<span>Show</span>`s need to be inside the 'container' divs. http://jsfiddle.net/M6wzh/1/

(The jquery code finds the first paragraph within the same parent element as the `<span>Show</span>` and expands it. Since none of the `<span>Show</span>`s were inside container elements, it simply found the first paragraph on the page and expanded that.)

Comment: thank you for the answer and explanation , if I have this span in JS like `return text.substring(0, len) + "&hellip;" + '<span>Show</span>';`  Is there a possible way to get it to work?

Comment: Yes you just need to change `$(this).parent().find("p:first")` to `$(this).parent()`, since the paragraph is now the span's parent element. http://jsfiddle.net/M6wzh/4/